# Why console app works but web app doesn't for HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: c#

I am using the exact same code base in a console application as I am in a web application.  Everything works fine until I get to this call in the web application:

```
// Send a request asynchronously, continue when complete
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(tokenEndpoint, jsonLoginPayload);
```

The console application returns with a response but in the web application it never comes back.

What am I missing?

Comment: Add reference to `System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll` and try to add this line to your code `System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;`

Comment: Ok I will try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have blocking issue on your `Async` method call due to Synchronization Context.

try with

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(tokenEndpoint,
    jsonLoginPayload).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Ok, I will try that.